# Split a div background color based on $index in ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, background, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am building a new UI where I am doing ng-repeat on an array and displaying elements in the array as radio buttons - inline.

HTML:

```
<div class="sliderticks-container survey-v2-slider-background" role="radiogroup">
  <div class="sliderticks focus-presenter" ng-repeat="answer in $ctrl.question.choices | orderBy: answer.orderIndex track by $index">
  </div>
</div>
```

I included the class "survey-v2-slider-background" in outer div which sets the background of the container that holds these radio buttons.
CSS:

```
.survey-v2-slider-background {
    background: rgba(202, 236, 244, 0.5)
}

.sliderticks-container {
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 0 17px;
            border-radius: 14px;
            cursor: pointer;
            .sliderticks {
                display: inline;
```

My requirement is to split the background color from left to right based on the radio button the user clicks. Suppose if the array has 7 elements and if the user clicks on element with index 4, the background color of the container should be different (say red) to left of index 4. To the right of index 4, it should be the default background color mentioned in css file for 'survey-v2-slider-background'.

Is there any way to get this?

I want the background split to look like this:
[image]

**What I tried:**

I came across linear-gradient which I can use like below but that's static percentage. I want it to be dynamic based on index selected.

```
.survey-v2-slider-background {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, rgba(202, 236, 244, 0.5) 0%);
}
```

Comment: I’d take a look at ng-class and add the desired background to the repeated div’s that are less than the selected $index. Of course it depends on what your code is for your inline radio buttons, which you should provide to give a better answer.

Comment: @tbone849 How does that help? I want the entire background less than index to be filled. Not just the background behind radio buttons.

Comment: Can you whip up a codepen or something of that nature? Would be easier to test out some thoughts.

Comment: So, I forgot to save the plunker.. Anyhow, you can use a second div (z-index: -1) that has absolute position from 0 to the right edge of the selected slidertick.  Just have to clean up the borders and padding a little.

Comment: Never used code pen but tried to put something up based on your input @kendavidson. Not sure if that's what you meant. https://codepen.io/kpab7/pen/agQpVw

Comment: Super primative, needs angularizing (directive) - https://plnkr.co/edit/d0h1FGutcwb2MxWmuxqm?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @kendavidson . That helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in the lines of what @kendavidson mentioned. Added a new div with position: absolute and Instead of doing it in controller, I just added ng-style with percentage condition in the html.

```
<div class="sliderticks-background survey-v2-slider-selected-background" ng-style = "{ width: ($ctrl.selectedOptionOrderIndex/($ctrl.question.choices.length-1)) * 100 + '%' }"></div>
```